# 2FA failing in Instaloader

Tags: python, instaloader

Trying to login to Instagram using Instaloader,

```
L = ig.Instaloader()
L.login(user, password)
L.two_factor_login(11111)
```

raises the following error

```
raise TwoFactorAuthRequiredException("Login error: two-factor authentication required.")
instaloader.exceptions.TwoFactorAuthRequiredException: Login error: two-factor authentication required.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://instaloader.github.io/module/instaloader.html#instaloader.Instaloader.login) mentions that `TwoFactorAuthRequiredException` is raised if the first step of 2FA login is done, and you should call `Instaloader.two_factor_login()` - but because the exception is raised, in your code, that call is never reached.

Try something like:

```
from instaloader.exceptions import TwoFactorAuthRequiredException

L = ig.Instaloader()

try:
    L.login(user, password)
except TwoFactorAuthRequiredException:
    L.two_factor_login(11111)
```

Comment: Worked!! Been using python for over a year, but still couldn't figure this out from the documentation.

Comment: i'm still getting the same error even after copy pasting your code